# jQuery .load() Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load some content with an AJAX call and AFTER the content is loaded, perform another action. In my example, that latter action is simply an alert but in my real-world example I'm attempting to focus on an input field.

```
$("#box").load("/favicon.png", function(response) {
     alert('do after the load');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u0cmmn5h/

As you can see in the fiddle, the alert fires BEFORE the favicon is actually loaded. Isn't the function supposed to fire AFTER the content has been loaded?

Comment: `alerts` and similar OS popups are poor design because are intrusive and blocking, page code execution will not continue unless specific user action is performed. Use some custom solution when possible. So in your case you'd better go with `console.log('do after the load');` for testing purposes.

Comment: You could wrap the function in [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise) or [jQuery's equivalent Deferred object](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/), thus making it chainable with `.then(function(){})` and others. Promises would resolve when JavaScript code resolves, which may not be the exact time of the image showing up on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback on `.load()` executes upon an http response, not when the image is rendered client side.

Comment: Got it. I think I should be using $.ajax() here instead. Do I still need to implement promises if I switch it to $.ajax() and put the event (alert in this case) as the success to the ajax() request?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using `load` on an image. Not sure what you have the `load` on a div.

The `load` method will be fired when the image `src` attribute changes and the image is successfully loaded (note if it fails this wont execute).

[.load() jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

```js
$(function() {
 $('img').load(function() {
   alert('done after load');
  }).attr('src', '/favicon.ico');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <img />
</div>
```